# SQL XML query (value) returning no results

Tags: sql, xquery

I'm trying to understand the value() method of querying XML but I can't seem to get it to return any results...

```
CREATE TABLE UserListing
(Data XML)

DECLARE @xmlValue xml

SET @xmlValue = (SELECT * FROM Users for XML PATH ('User'), ROOT ('UserListing'), TYPE)

INSERT INTO UserListing values (@xmlValue)
```

Query:

```
select Data from UserListing
```

Returns:

```
<UserListing>
 <User>
  <userId>Bob</userId>
  <EmailAddress>bob@bob.com</EmailAddress>
 </User>
 <User>
  <userId>Bill</userId>
  <EmailAddress>bill@bill.com</EmailAddress>
 </User>
</UserListing>
```

Query:

```
select Data from UserListing
where
  Data.value('(/UserListing/User/userId)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like 'Bob'
```

...No results, but the column header is returned?

Comment: your query looks fine, it could be another issue, I tried it and it works

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried again with no luck: 

use tempdb

CREATE TABLE USERS (
USERID NVARCHAR (10),
EMAILADDRESS NVARCHAR (20))


INSERT INTO USERS VALUES (
'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com')


CREATE TABLE UserListing
(Data XML)

DECLARE atxmlValue xml

SET atxmlValue = (SELECT * FROM Users for XML PATH ('User'), ROOT ('UserListing'), TYPE)

INSERT INTO UserListing values (@xmlValue)


select Data from UserListing
where
Data.value('(/UserListing/User/USERID)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like 'Bob'